# how to load multibyte character to SQL DW external table pointing to BLOB

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to load the multibyte character with length more than 7000 char from my External Tables to SQL DW Internal tables. I have the data stores in a compressed format in BLOB Storage and External tables are pointed to the BLOB Storage Location.

External table with varchar supports till 4000 charater. is there any other approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PolyBase to load the data directly into the SQL DW production tables (dbo.) from the Azure Blob Storage via the linked External (ext.) tables, you should be able to get around the external table limitation.

This tutorial walks you through the process: [Tutorial: Load New York Taxicab data to Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/load-data-from-azure-blob-storage-using-polybase)

Answer (score 0):

How have you defined your database column?

The limit for a varchar is 8,000 characters, but an nvarchar is 4,000 characters. Because you're using multi-byte characters I guess you're using nvarchar.

Consider using nvarchar(max) as your target type for this column. (EDIT) As pointed out in the comments, an EXTERNAL table does not support (max).

Comment: external table not supporting nvarchar(max).

Comment: Do you control the export format? Can you split the column in two, then concatenate the pieces after loading?

Comment: Is there any other approach without split column in External table & join in internal table?. As we are populating comments column may have more than 8000 char and may increase.